# How to add Vaadin libraries in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin

How can I add new libraries in NetBeans when I create a Vaadin Web Application Project? There is no "Libraries" node in project properties.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Vaadin 7.4.5

Comment: The Netbeans Vaadin plugin is creating maven based projects. So you have to add the required dependencies in the pom.xml file.